# Exception Behaviour without errorChannel on inbound adapters

Tags: spring-integration

I have `int-aws:sqs-message-driven-channel-adapter` on which if I set the `errorChannel`, the downstream exceptions go there.

However, when I don't set an `errorChannel`, the exception does not get logged. It does not go to the errorChannel which is expected. Is there a way, that such exceptions at least get logged? Is there a default `errorlogger` which can simply log such errors?

**UPDATE**

Posting `XML` and `DSL` config as per the comments. The `error` is simulated in the persistence layer by setting `null` for a `@NotBlank` field on the `ServiceObject`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
    xmlns:int-jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jpa"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jpa https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jpa/spring-integration-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws.xsd">

  <int:channel id="serviceLogChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
      <int:wire-tap channel="loggingChannel"/>
    </int:interceptors>
  </int:channel>

  <int-aws:sqs-message-driven-channel-adapter sqs="amazonSQS"
      auto-startup="true"
      channel="serviceLogChannel"
      id="sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter"
      queues="${app.queue-name}"
      max-number-of-messages="10"
      visibility-timeout="5"
      wait-time-out="20"
      error-channel="errorChannel"/>

  <int:chain input-channel="serviceLogChannel">
    <int:json-to-object-transformer type="ServiceObject"/>
    <int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter entity-class="ServiceObject"
        persist-mode="PERSIST"
        entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory">
      <int-jpa:transactional/>
    </int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
  </int:chain>

  <int:logging-channel-adapter log-full-message="true"
      logger-name="tapInbound"
      id="loggingChannel"/>

  <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" expression="@reThrow.rethrow(payload)" order="100"/>

</beans>
```

The `ReThrow` service-activator:

```java
@Component
public class ReThrow {

    public void rethrow(Exception exception) throws Exception {
        throw exception;
    }

}
```

The DSL config for the same is :

```java
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer createSqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
        AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync,
        MessageChannel serviceChannel,
        MessageChannel errorChannel,
        @Value("${app.queue-name}") String queueName) {
        SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
            new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazonSQSAsync, queueName);
        adapter.setVisibilityTimeout(5);
        adapter.setWaitTimeOut(20);
        adapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        adapter.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(serviceChannel);
        adapter.setErrorChannel(errorChannel);
        adapter.setMessageDeletionPolicy(SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NO_REDRIVE);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow messageProcessingFlow(
        MessageChannel serviceChannel, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(serviceChannel)
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(ServiceObject.class))
            .handle(
                Jpa.outboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                    .entityClass(ServiceObject.class)
                    .persistMode(PersistMode.PERSIST),
                e -> e.transactional())
            .get();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorProcessingFlow(MessageChannel errorChannel) {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel)
            .handle(
                m -> {
                    throw (RuntimeException) m.getPayload();
                })
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel serviceChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is fully based on the `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` from Spring Cloud AWS and that one just delegates to a listener we provide. Looking to the code there is just no any error handling. So, the best way to deal with it at the moment to explicitly set an `error-channel="errorChannel"` and it is going to be logged via default logger subscribed to that global `errorChannel`.

And yes: it is not expected to go to the `errorChannel` by default. I'm not sure that there is such an official claim in our docs. Probably better to think about it as "no error channel by default", so it is up to underlying protocol client to handle thrown errors. Since there is no one there, then we don't have choice unless set error channel explicitly.

Comment: When I add `erroChannel` to `int-aws:sqs-message-driven-channel-adapter`, the message is now considered to be processed successfully, i.e. `exception` not thrown back to the caller (`SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory`), hence `redrive` is not triggered, and the message never reaches the `DLQ`. What I want to achieve is log via `errorChannel` and still throw the exception to the caller, so `redrive` is triggered. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Or do I need to change the approach? May be this cannot be achieved using `NO_REDRIVE`, since it requires both, routing to `errorChannel` and also throwing back to the `caller`.

Comment: Well, just make a service activator to that `errorChannel` which will get an `Exception` as an argument to re-throw. This way the error is going to be logged and comes back to the listener container for redrive.

Comment: Channel 'auditlog.errorChannel' has 2 subscriber(s). However, the `logging adapter` never gets called, since I think they are called on the `sender's` thread and the `rethrow` subscriber executes first. How can I have both subscribers independent of each other without the `rethrow` going to the `errorChannel`?. If I declare a custom `errorChannel` just to add a `taskExecutor` to solve this, then the `rethrow` will go to the `errorChannel` (due to aysnc) causing an infinite loop on the `erroChannel`.

Comment: Correct , it cannot rethrow from a new thread. Why do you add an executor to that channel at all? Just add `order=“100”` to your rethrow service activator based on the standard error channel

Comment: The `order` does not work. Also, when I checked using DSL config, the default error logger adapter gets added to the handlers [`OrderedAwareCopyOnWriteArraySet`] before the `service-activator`. In `XML` config, it's the other way even with `order=100`. I have switched to `DSL` now.

Comment: Would you mind to show your final config in the edit for the question? I still have doubts that we talk about slightly different matters...

Comment: Both `XML` and `DSL` config added. Thank you very much for your time and help with this. Using the `XML` config, the error is not logged, since the `error logger adapter` is second to the `service-activator` in  handlers [`OrderedAwareCopyOnWriteArraySet`]

Comment: Please, raise a GH issue that there is no consistency with subscribers order into a global `errorChannel` in XML & Java DSL config.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3555 Thank You !